# Program crashed after one line input. How to fix?

Tags: c, pointers, getline

I have made a program of getline function of mine. Which takes input till a '\n' is encountered and shifts to the next input. Also I have used pointer arrays here to store the string inputs, but the program crashes after the first string input. What's the problem?

This is the code of the program. I have tried to debug it but it but I can't find the problem here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void getline2(char *s)
{
    char c;
    while((c=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        *s=c;
        s++;
    }
    *s='\0';
}

int main()
{
    char *lines[3];
    int i=0;
    while(i<3)
    {
        getline2(lines[i]);
        i++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s", lines[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I input the first line after pressing the enter the program crashes.

Comment: You have declared an array of pointers but have not allocated memory for the pointers. Your code has undefined behavior because of that.

Comment: Curious: who or what text suggested putting a `"\n"` at the _start_ of `"\n%s"`?

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You really should be able to find such bugs by yourself.

Comment: Besides the obvious errors in calling it that others have pointed out, your `getline2` has pretty much the exact same semantics as `getline()` (minus the correct handling of EOF conditions), so it's broken by design, as it uses an external buffer but doesn't allow to pass in the buffer size.

Comment: If the `printf` loop is not relevant, then it should be removed from the [mcve].

Comment: @WernerHenze `printf()` is relevant and good here as it shows an example of how OP intended to use the input.  From time to time, a program crashes lurks there and not in the input code portion.  IMO, a question without output is not a [MCVE].

Comment: @chux I disagree. It crashes prior to printf already. The while loop in `main` is probably noise too. `getline2(lines[0])` would have sufficed to produce the crash.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks, that is what I believe, too. It perfectly shows why an mcve is so useful. It helps narrowing down the problem and may lead the questioner to the right answer without the need to ask the question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `char *lines[3];` defines an array of `char` pointers. The pointers themselves do not point to any valid memory *automatically*. Unless initialized properly, attempt to use (or de-reference) them would lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are two common approach of achieving what you want (based on your requirement):

- Allocate a size at compile time and length-limit your input [i.e., pass the size of the buffer as a function argument, like [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)]
- Allocate memory at run time (allocator functions, [`malloc()` and family](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)) and resize based on the input length.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to supplying a `char*` which points to valid memory (as well suggested by others), `getline2()` has other weaknesses to address.

**Unknown size**

`getline2()` does not know how many characters can be saved.  Suggest accepting a size parameter and adjust code to prevent overfilling `s`.

```
// void getline2(char *s)
void getline2(char *s, size_t sz)
```

**Infinite loop on `EOF`**

When `stdin` is closed or a rare input error occurs, `getchar()` can perpetual return `EOF` and never exit the loop.

**257 values do not fit in `char`**

`int fgetc()` returns values in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  Use `int c;` and test loop for `c != '\n' && c != EOF`

```
// char c;
// while((c=getchar())!='\n')
int c;
while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c != EOF)
```